# Generating four random numbers and append it to DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm practicing my knowledge on basic JavaScript and this is my first ever project. here's the problem:

I like to generate a random numbers of four and append it to the DOM, so whenever users press the spacebar a random numbers of four will generate, and visible to the website rather than having to look at the console.

I'm done caching the DOM using querySelecter and listen for keydown for the button.

```
let randNum;
const numArr = [];
const box = document.querySelector('.box');

function genNum (e) {

  const button = document.querySelector(`.button[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
  if(!button) return;

  numArr.forEach(numbers => {
    randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
  });
};

window.addEventListener('keydown', genNum)
```

The main purpose is to generate 4 random numbers from 0 to 9, and append it to the DOM call box. Whenever a user press on space bar, they will see any random numbers on the front end

Comment: What are you running stuck on? You only need to assign it into a div (or something similar)

Comment: `numArr` is empty, so `numArr.forEach` will never call its callback. Separately, if it did, it doesn't make sense to overwrite the value of `randNum` every time the callback is called. You also don't ever actually do anything with `randNum`. I think you need to keep working with this, go through some more tutorials and/or a good beginner's book, etc., before asking what to do on SO.

Comment: You're iterating on empty array your `Math.random` will never execute. And numbers in forEach function will be number not numbers but only if numArray already have some values. You need to create array with 4 values or use normal for loop.

Comment: @Martijn I'm stuck on generating a random numbers and append it to the box.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Hey Thanks for the critic given, i agree with your advice definitely will implement it in future. The reason i used a forEach method is because i've created a boxes of four on the front-end, and this is my mistake on my part, should have included it in the description my bad. So the main purpose is to put that four random numbers to each boxes and whenever i press the space-bar it will generate a numbers. Its similar to playing lotto. Thank again!

Comment: @jcubic Thanks for the advice will look into it :D

Comment: Thanks again everyone really appreciate the help and the critic, which i took it positively to keep the fuel running in me Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `numArr` is empty, so its `.forEach()` won't do much good. I guess you want to always count to 4 instead.

```js
const box = document.querySelector('.box');

function genNum (e) {
  const button = document.querySelector(`.button[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
  if(!button) return;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    box.textContent += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + ","
  }
}

window.addEventListener('keydown', genNum)
```

```html
<input type=hidden class=button value=spacebar data-key=32>
<div class=box></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you intend to append the numbers to the DOM element with class *box* (i.e. `.box`).

**Some pointers:**

1. `const box` is actually **an array**. Thus, `const box` will not point towards the DOM element `.box`, but rather an array containing all matches to DOM
   elements with the class name *box*. (After all, classes are not
   unique, unlike IDs).

   ^ I assume that this is your problem, and to solve it and get the
   actual DOM element, you could use
   `const box = document.querySelector('.box')[0];` or
   `const box = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0];`. 
   (What you are actually doing is getting the first DOM element matching something with the class *box*)
2. As many users have mentioned, you are iterating over an empty array `numArr`. Use simple for loop and `Math.random()` instead. *(See code below)*
3. I do not know why you decided to use the code `const button = document.querySelector(`.button[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);` to check for a spacebar keypress. Use `if(e.keyCode != 32) return; //32 is the keycode for space` instead.
4. As a good practice, use keyup instead of keydown (`window.addEventListener('keyup', genNum)`), as keydown will fire as long as the space is pressed downwards.

**OVERALL**

```
let randNum;
const box = document.querySelector('.box')[0]; //alternatively, document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0];

function genNum (e) {
    if(e.keyCode != 32) return; //32 is ASCII code for spacebar.

    //Actual appending of text to the DOM element box. 
    //Here I assume that your box is empty; otherwise adding numbers will just override whatever is inside the box
    box.innerHTML = '';
    let i = 0;
    const nNums = 4;
    for(i=0;i<nNums;i++){
        randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        box.innerHTML += randNum+" ";
    }
};

window.addEventListener('keydown', genNum)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help, appreciate it much. I really like to be more specific, but i past 152 long of explanation so i can't send it. To cut short, i've tried your given example code and Thanks again Sam :) unfortunately, i've got an error pertaining to the innerHTML is not defined, i will look into it do what i've learn and will get back to you through this channel Cheers mate!

Comment: On point 1, if you were to console.log(typeof box); you will see an object rather than Array.

Comment: Array is an Object, so even if you `console.log(typeof [])`, you'd get Object as well